# How do I let my client post articles on his blog page on a website I designed with (HTML CSS JS PHP)?

Tags: php, database, dynamic, blogs

I have designed a website that provides blog page, what my client wants is that he could add articles to his blog and a new page should be created for every article , also on the main blog page there are 8 links to latest posts so the title of latest post be also there on the top of all blog pages?

Answer (score 2):

Let's start from here:
https://technosmarter.com/php/how-to-create-blog-using-php-and-mysql-database

But first you need to learn php,mysql,js, html  and css

Answer (score 0):

You need to learn database and store your data then you can show those data in your website dynamically. [Check this](https://github.com/Nisshan) code for some knowledge or [check this tutorial](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-8-from-scratch) for reference